# Do not get Postgres user created when starting docker compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have `docker-compose.dev.yaml` file where I specified configuration for starting `PostgreSQL` and other containers. But the problem here is when I enter `docker compose -f docker-compose.dev.yaml up --build` command, I do not get my user created.

To begin with, here is my `yaml` file configurations for postgres:

```
services:

  # PostgreSQL
  db:
    image: postgres:16.1-alpine
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "sh -c 'pg_isready -U ${POSTGRES_USER} -d ${POSTGRES_DB}'" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3


volumes:
  db:
```

Here is `.env` file, located in the same directory as the `docker-compose.dev.yaml`:

```
POSTGRES_DB=dbStartup
POSTGRES_USER=dbUser
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=dbPass
```

And finally logs when I run `docker compose -f docker-compose.dev.yaml up --build`  after *deleting* volume for the container (I also tried to clean all docker data including all images, volumes, containers, cache):

```
startup-db-1        | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
startup-db-1        | This user must also own the server process.
startup-db-1        | 
startup-db-1        | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
startup-db-1        | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
startup-db-1        | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
startup-db-1        | 
startup-db-1        | Data page checksums are disabled.
startup-db-1        | 
startup-db-1        | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
startup-db-1        | creating subdirectories ... ok
startup-db-1        | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
startup-db-1        | selecting default max_connections ... 100
startup-db-1        | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
startup-db-1        | selecting default time zone ... UTC
startup-db-1        | creating configuration files ... ok
startup-db-1        | running bootstrap script ... ok
startup-db-1        | sh: locale: not found
startup-db-1        | 2024-01-27 01:20:34.995 UTC [30] WARNING:  no usable system locales were found
startup-db-1        | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
startup-db-1        | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
startup-db-1        | initdb: hint: You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
startup-db-1        | syncing data to disk ... ok
startup-db-1        | 
startup-db-1        | 
startup-db-1        | Success. You can now start the database server using:
startup-db-1        | 
startup-db-1        |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
startup-db-1        | 
startup-db-1        | waiting for server to start....2024-01-27 01:20:35.690 UTC [36] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.1 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 13.2.1_git20231014) 13.2.1 20231014, 64-bit
startup-db-1        | 2024-01-27 01:20:35.691 UTC [36] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
startup-db-1        | 2024-01-27 01:20:35.697 UTC [39] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-01-27 01:20:35 UTC
startup-db-1        | 2024-01-27 01:20:35.702 UTC [36] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
startup-db-1        |  done
startup-db-1        | server started
startup-db-1        | CREATE DATABASE
startup-db-1        | 
startup-db-1        | 
startup-db-1        | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
startup-db-1        | 
startup-db-1        | 2024-01-27 01:20:35.850 UTC [36] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
startup-db-1        | waiting for server to shut down....2024-01-27 01:20:35.851 UTC [36] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
startup-db-1        | 2024-01-27 01:20:35.855 UTC [36] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 42) exited with exit code 1
startup-db-1        | 2024-01-27 01:20:35.859 UTC [37] LOG:  shutting down
startup-db-1        | 2024-01-27 01:20:35.861 UTC [37] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
startup-db-1        | 2024-01-27 01:20:35.910 UTC [37] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 925 buffers (5.6%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.020 s, sync=0.025 s, total=0.051 s; sync files=301, longest=0.002 s, average=0.001 s; distance=4269 kB, estimate=4269 kB; lsn=0/191BA30, redo lsn=0/191BA30
startup-db-1        | 2024-01-27 01:20:35.919 UTC [36] LOG:  database system is shut down
startup-db-1        |  done
startup-db-1        | server stopped
startup-db-1        | 
startup-db-1        | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
startup-db-1        | 
startup-db-1        | 2024-01-27 01:20:35.979 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.1 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 13.2.1_git20231014) 13.2.1 20231014, 64-bit
startup-db-1        | 2024-01-27 01:20:35.980 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
startup-db-1        | 2024-01-27 01:20:35.980 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
startup-db-1        | 2024-01-27 01:20:35.982 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
startup-db-1        | 2024-01-27 01:20:35.987 UTC [52] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-01-27 01:20:35 UTC
startup-db-1        | 2024-01-27 01:20:35.992 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Also, when I try to do something with the `db` container for postgres  (create migration from `Python` to `PostgreSQL`, for example) the operation failes with these logs:

```
startup-db-1        | 2024-01-27 02:08:30.527 UTC [44] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "startUser"
startup-db-1        | 2024-01-27 02:08:30.527 UTC [44] DETAIL:  Role "startUser" does not exist.
startup-db-1        |   Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf" line 128: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
```

I have been struggling with the problem for two days and even can not find something useful that can help me solve it. I have already tried deleting all volumes, images, cache, containers, but it did not help me.

I would be very grateful for any help with the issue.

P.S. Sorry if I made some mistakes in the text, as English is not my native language.

Comment: The `.env` file you quote uses a user name `dbUser`, but your eventual error message suggests the application is configured for a user `startUser`.  Do these names match in your actual system?

Comment: I didn't notice that.. So you suggest that there may be some problems with the enviroments? P.S. I tried using `enviroment` in the file and specify varibles for postgres inside using `env_file` where I specify the name of file and issue persists.. It seems that the `PostgreSQL` service is looking for `startUser`, but I have no idea why

Answer (score -1):

The problem turned out to be so silly, that I even didn't notice it. I used `DSN` for the database with variables (e.g. `POSTGRES_USER`) different from variables specified in `.env`..

Comment: Don't worry, that won't be the last time you do something like that.... there is nothing more consistent than human fallibility ... `:)`